# orbeon : bind xforms instance with xml schema complex type

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to bind XForms instances according to an XML Schema. It works fine with facets, like in the following case, where `ValeurNoteType` is a restriction on an `xs:decimal` type :

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('note-template')">
    <xforms:bind nodeset="Valeur" type="ValeurNoteType"/>
</xforms:bind>
```

XForms 1.1 doesn't seems to support complex types for binding, like in the following example, where `ExamenType` is a sequence :

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('examen-template')">
    <xforms:bind nodeset="Examen" type="ExamenType"/>
</xforms:bind>
```

What I want is to avoid to write `<xforms:bind nodeset="Titre" required="true()"/>` for every element of the `ExamenType` type for which there is a `Min Occurs = 1` in the xml schema (or other conditions, like `xs:date` type for an element in the sequence and so on).

Is there a way to do it with Orbeon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XForms 1.1 is clear in specifying how the `type` attribute is handled:

> "The `type` model item property is not applied to instance nodes that contain child elements. The `type` model item property associates a datatype (as defined in [XML Schema part 2]) with the string-value (as defined in [XPath 1.0]) of an instance node. The datatype being associated can be obtained from a simpleType definition or a simpleContent definition from a complexType. If the datatype cannot be obtained as just described, then the Default Value of `xsd:string` is used."

In other words, the `type` attribute only works as a way to validate text content, not the structure of the document.

If a schema is present, the entire instance is validated (Orbeon forms has extensions to control that, see [Validation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-validation#TOC-Controlling-the-XML-Schema-validation-mode)) and nodes can be marked as invalid as well in that process, including due to complex content validation. But I am not sure if this will help in your case. In any case, this is a process separate from the handling of the `type` attribute.

Comment: In my app, I'm pulling out of exist a big instance which is validated by a schema. When I post it back, the validation works fine (and I can handle/display the errors if any). What I'm looking for is a way to reflect the structure of the schema and/or changes made to it in an "automatic" way in my forms instances. Obviously, it's not with the `type`attribute ! Thanks a lot to have made that clear to me !